# FastAPI 422 Unprocessable Entity when using with POST Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Tags: python-3.x, api, request, fastapi, pydantic

I am using FastAPI and I want to get a POST request by using FastAPI pydantic or FastAPI body object and It doesn't work...

**Here's my FastAPI Code:**

```
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI
from fastapi.params import Body


app = FastAPI()

@app.post('/messagebird/flow_v2')
async def messagebird_flow(request: Request, payload: dict = Body(...) ):

    body = await request.body() #This works! (I don't like this way)

    print(payload) #This DOESN'T work
```

**Here's the error that I get when using payload: dict = Body(...) or pydantic structure:**

```
INFO:     127.0.0.1:59870 - "POST /messagebird/flow_v2 HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity
```

**
Here's the Request:**

```
POST /messagebird/flow_v2 HTTP/1.1
Host: 2d40-83-43-203-143.eu.ngrok.io
User-Agent: MessageBird Flows API/2.0
Content-Length: 616
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Messagebird-Request-Timestamp: 1669666185
Messagebird-Signature: PVShU4B/UrrhcK5jnEzYBYtwOy7NdDkYvviqEPs+Pmo=
Messagebird-Signature-Jwt: eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJNZXNzYWdlQmlyZCIsIm5iZiI6MTY2OTY2NjE4NSwiZXhwIjoxNjY5NjY2MjQ1LCJqdGkiOiIwOWQyOWQ5YS0zZDM1LTQyYjktYTI3OS05ODQ1NTIzZWY0N2YiLCJ1cmxfaGFzaCI6IjRlOGVhMzM5ODUxNmZiYjE5MTg2MWFlMzgyYTdiNjc1ODAyMzVkNjUwNDIzZmFiNDE2Mjg0NGNkY2RmMTgzZDMiLCJwYXlsb2FkX2hhc2giOiJiNTUwNTlhMDA1OWU3ZDc5NjU5MDljOWIzNjM4NDI4Njk5ZDFjNzdhNDcyNzIxODVkMTgyNDgwYWUxOGFiNzkwIn0.tcmw9i0-UcNilXjCfixzJnp7m4JX9k2YzMDBFczyG_o
X-Forwarded-For: 34.90.201.190
X-Forwarded-Proto: https

agent=Luc%C3%ADa&channelId=6b413a63-46be-4dbc-bad6-d5a2ed28499a&company=COMPANY&conversationId=1068fe69521b46f6b179dc982f3acda3&flowId=a9343b4e-859a-44af-81b2-ffb17d8f8c45&flowRevisionId=f45ed841-a629-4891-b813-a4f29da68d6a&from=6b413a63-46be-4dbc-bad6-d5a2ed28499a&invocationId=54fb2d37-09ce-4db8-9bef-ded0299d8238&lastConversationId=1068fe69521b46f6b179dc982f3acda3&lastMessageSentId=bde39e8661ef44f9a7ed6ee0ca4d2593&lastMessageSentTo=34660049970&messageBirdRequestId=93ba7f30-6f58-11ed-b3a3-2e5ef0e7161f&problem=PROBLEM&sleep=5+seconds&solution=SOLUTION&to=%2B34660049970&uuid=bie594NFWQVstFWWvziieU&wait=24+hours
```

**I've tried:**

- Using Pydantic and fastapi.params import Body object but didn't work

Comment: Only works with aplication/json content type

Comment: If you're going to use regular POST variables, you'll have to use `agent: str = Form()` to tell FastAPI to populate `agent` from the `agent` key in the posted data. If you want to use a pydantic model, use `application/json` and POST a JSON object as the body (or use a regular function with arguments as the form variable names that return a dict as a dependency, as shown in https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/dependencies/classes-as-dependencies/)

Comment: Awesome @MatsLindh!

This solved my problem! 

Do you know if there's a way to get all =Form() params at once? Do I have to get each param individually?

Comment: `await request.form()` as shown in Starlette's documentation: https://www.starlette.io/requests/#body